# npm live-server not running on mobile

Tags: npm-live-server

Everything runs correctly when I start the npm live-server from my laptop, but when I type the address on the iPhone's browser 127.0.0.1:8080 it says the address can't be found.

I remember before that when running the live server from the terminal you can also see the web page from mobile too.
I'm not using `file://` to run the page.

Appreciate the help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server), I can see that it seems to work like ng serve, and you need to add the parameter `--host 0.0.0.0` to make the server bind to all IPs and not just 127.0.0.1 (which is not reachable from your phone)